# re.sub replace multiple pattern each with different word in a single call

Tags: python, regex

I have a file name in this format,

```
remote_execute___jenkin%.java
remtoe__plat_jenk.java
```

I want to replace all occurance of two or three `_` with single `_`,

which I have done like this,

```
re.sub('_{2,3}','_',name)
```

this works and replace all occurrence of two or three `_` with single `_`. But in the same `re.sub` call, i need to replace `.java` with `.jav`,

I did this to match both `.java` and `underscores`,

```
\.java$|_{2,3}
```

but how can I replace `.java` in the same `re.sub` call without using another `re.sub` after replacing `underscores`,

right now i am doing it like this,

```
name = re.sub('_{2,3}','_',name)
name = re.sub('\.java$','jav',name)
```

I want to do above in one `re.sub` call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your example data you could use:

[`_(?=_)|(?<=\.jav)a$`](https://regex101.com/r/KjYxGb/1)

```
import re
name = "remote_execute___jenkin%.java"
print(re.sub('_(?=_)|(?<=\.jav)a$', "", name))
```

This would match

- `_(?=_)` Match an underscore and use a positive lookahead to assert that what follows is an underscore which would match the the leading underscores and do not match the last in `__` or `___`
- `|` or
- `(?<=\.jav)a$` Positive lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is `.jav` and match an `a` at the end of the line

If the occurences of an underscore must be 2 times or 3 times you might use:

[`(?<!_)_{1,2}(?=_[^_])|(?<=\.jav)a$`](https://regex101.com/r/QYNRM6/1)

The part that matches 2 or 3 underscores:

- `(?<!_)` Use a negative lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is not an underscore
- `_{1,2}` match an underscore 1 or 2 times
- `(?=_[^_])` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is an underscore followed by not an underscore

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/GWLN97548)

Answer (score 1):

Nested `re.sub` will work

```
name = re.sub('_{2,3}','_',re.sub('\.java$','jav',name))
```

Comment: but this uses two re.sub again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33642769/7265871 This should help